# "me, him and Clara"

Tags: grammaticality, subjects, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, coordinating-conjunctions

My friend is starting to write a small book. She wanted me to check the grammar so she can be sure about it. She has a sentence that goes, "me, him and Clara started hanging out in middle school." The thing I'm confused about is, "me, him and Clara," Is this proper grammar for a first person view including three people?

Comment: No; it should be "He, Clara, and I" (or "Clara, he, and I").

Comment: It depends. Is your friend writing this sentence as part of the narrative, or is she quoting a character speaking in dialect? Even if it is part of the narrative, it would depend on the "voice" she is using in the story.

Comment: As your question has been closed for duplicate, I recommend that you take a close look at sumelic´s answer. It is a balanced approach to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

NO!!!

''Clara and I both started hanging out with him in middle school'' might work ... as would ''In middle school I started hanging out with him, and Clara did too''